# How to query reference collection in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm writing a map function in mongodb for using mapReduce.
I have two colletions: A and B.
The map function is like this:

```
var map=function()
{ 
var key=this.name; 
var info = query_collection_B();
emit(key,info);
}
```

My question is how to write the function query_collection_B()?

I tried this way:

```
function query_collection_B()
{
sth = db.B.find();
return sth;
}
```

But When I run my mapReduce like this way:

```
db.A.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:'C'})
```

I get error like this :

```
map reduce failed:{
"errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: B is not defined near '...'",
"code" : 16722,
"ok" : 0
}
```

All the operations are done in mongoshell javascript.

Comment: Map-reduce is not designed to resolve Joins. You can't do that. Read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-map-function

Comment: So seems there is no way to get this done in a single map-reduce operation, I should separate the operation to two stages?

Comment: Yes you need to separate it into two phases. You should consider restructuring your schema to avoid making joins.